# How to apply single-variable function to multiple lists in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am using the tidytransit package to analyze 7 GTFS feeds in R. Tidytransit presents these feeds as lists of dataframes. I want to execute an operation on each of these lists (set_servicepattern(x)) but don't feel like typing it out seven times, so would like to build a function that loops the operation across all seven lists. I've attempted this with lapply, but cannot seem to figure out how to get the result from lapply out of the list structure back into each of its sub-lists to overwrite the input list. Suggestions?

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
nyc_subway <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/subway/google_transit.zip")
bus_bk <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/bus/google_transit_brooklyn.zip")
bus_qn <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/bus/google_transit_queens.zip")
bus_bx <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/bus/google_transit_bronx.zip")
bus_ma <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/bus/google_transit_manhattan.zip")
bus_si <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/bus/google_transit_staten_island.zip")
bus_bc <- read_gtfs("http://web.mta.info/developers/data/busco/google_transit.zip")

list_2 <- list(nyc_subway, bus_bk, bus_qn, bus_bc, bus_bx, bus_ma, bus_si)

a <- function(x){ 
  set_servicepattern(x)
  return(x)}

lapply(list_2, a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to overwrite the objects, create a named `list` and then use `list2env` (not recommended as it is better to keep it in the `list`)

```
names(list_2) <- c('nyc_subway', 'bus_bk', 'bus_qn',
            'bus_bc', 'bus_bx', 'bus_ma', 'bus_si')
list2env(list_2, .GlobalEnv)
```